# Setting function to accept arguments of the form startIndex:stopIndex

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

For example:

```
print(readLines('B:\input.txt', 0, 3)) //0 and 3 are start and end indexes
```

Would become:

```
print(readLines('B:\input.txt', 0:3))
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by turning the argument into a string:

```
print(readLines('B:\input.txt', "0:3"))
```

and then unpacking it in the function:

```
def readLines(text, index):
    start, stop = index.split(':')
```

Comment: It worked, seems like you also have to convert them to integers first or python will think they're floats. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.islice:

```
from itertools import islice
def read_lines(it,start,stop):
  return list(islice(it,start, stop))
print(read_lines([1,2,3,4,5,6],0,3))
[1, 2, 3]
```

On a file:

```
from itertools import islice


def read_lines(f, start, stop):
    with open(f) as f:
        return list(islice(f, start, stop))
```

If you want just the  string output use `return " ".join(islice(f, start, stop))`

If you want to work on the lines just iterate over the islice object:

```
def read_lines(f, start, stop):
    with open(f) as f:
        for line in islice(f, start, stop):
            do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I already have a coded function, I just wanted to know how I could change the arguments needed from start and stop to start:stop.